# Django: How to include pk when to export Geojson using dumpdata?

Tags: django, geojson, dumpdata

I am using Django 'dumpdata' to export database table to Geojson file.

```
$python manage.py dumpdata --format=geojson > test.geojson
```

However, the geojson file does not contain pk (auto incremented integer). Is there any way to export the pk to the geojson file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try creating a `serializers.py` in one of your apps, and subclass the [geojson serializer](https://github.com/django/django/blob/ca1f4390c432ba69898219a0f7d50c09b3a75781/django/contrib/gis/serializers/geojson.py#L13) from `django.contrib.gis`.

In your app config, you will need to register your serializers module so that you can use it with the `dumpdata` command. You can see how the gis app does it [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/c00335997744196738368f46c30ef2eeaa0ac849/django/contrib/gis/apps.py).